# Auralocalizationservice error after summer '17 update

Tags: lightning, calendar, date-picker, summer-17

I have a date picker that is custom built by using static resources in lightning component. This is already existing and working fine.
since the summer 17 update, it started throwing the error

> "AuraLocalizationService.parseDateTime(): Locale 'undefined' is not
>   available. Falls back to the locale in $Locale.langLocale: en_US".

I assume it is the error in the static resources. I dont see "AuraLocalizationService" anywhere in my lightning components or vf pages.

Wanted to get some insights on this?

Where do I start?

Screenshot:
[image]

Update: 5/18

The calendar works fine but the manualdatechnage doesn't work. When I do a date change manually via input, the goes till the controller js but doesn't execute the helper. Not sure what I'm missing here. Follwoing are the components.

Input Components:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="dataChangeEvent" type="c:DateChange" description="The event fired when a valid date is set" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="onFocus" type="c:DateChangeEvent" description="The event fired when the user focuses on the component."/>


    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="text"
               aura:id="inputText"
               placeholder="{!v.placeholder}"
               value="{!v.value}"
               format="{!v.format}"
               class="{!v.class + ' input'}"
               onchange="{!c.handleDateChange}"
               onfocus="{!c.handleFocus}"/>

    </div>
```

Controller Js:

```
handleDateChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.dir('handledatechange***:'+helper);
        var value = event.target.value;
        console.log('inside controller:::'+value);
        helper.doUpdate(component, event);
    },
```

Helper:

```
doUpdate: function (component,event) {
    conosle.log('**event');
    //var value = event.getParam("value") || event.getParam("arguments").value;
    var value = event.target.value;
    if (!value) {
        return;
    }
    conosle.log('**event manual input**:'+value);
    var localizedValue = $A.localizationService.translateFromLocalizedDigits(value);
    var formattedDate = localizedValue;
    if (value) {
        var date = $A.localizationService.parseDateTimeUTC(localizedValue, this.format, true);

        if (date) {
            date = $A.localizationService.translateFromOtherCalendar(date);
            formattedDate = $A.localizationService.formatDateUTC(date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
            //fire event if value different from attribute value
            var currentValue = component.get("v.value");
            if (currentValue !== formattedDate){
                //emit an event!
                var dataChangeEvent = component.getEvent("dataChangeEvent");

                dataChangeEvent.setParams({"data" : {"value":formattedDate} });
                dataChangeEvent.fire();
            }
        }
    }
    component.set("v.value", formattedDate);
    console.log('formatted date:****'+formattedDate);
},
```

[image]

Comment: If it's my picker -https://github.com/rapsacnz/DatePicker - I'm working on a fix and will post it up here when I'm done.

Comment: (Salesforce introduced a breaking change to the localization service) https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_locale_api.htm

Comment: @CasparHarmer thank you for the response. yes, it is the date picker.

Comment: Is that an error or a warning?

Comment: This is a warning message. The calendar opens, but not able to select date. Please refer to the screenshot for the actual warning.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I found a weird behavior. it w click the date picker icon and thows errro when you click on the input entry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58472/discussion-between-anurag-a-and-caspar-harmer).

Comment: @AnuragA -Check out http://www.lightningstrike.io - for the most use component implementations by Appiphony - Datepicker component already built for you

Comment: Ok, I'm done - the issues have been fixed. Note several new components that you will need - Select, InputDate, DateTimeLib, DataChange

Comment: Hi, have you tried implementing the changes? If you pull in lightningstrike.io, you are going to end up with a heap of extra components in your org, some of which you may not want.

Comment: @CasparHarmerI'm trying to implement your changes. Getting some of teh reference error, but working on it. Have a question, I could see we are still using locale. like  var firstDayOfWeek = $A.get("$Locale.firstDayOfWeek"), doesn't it cause problem with summer '17. In release notes, it said the locale attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, this issue is directly caused by the `ui:inputDate` component provided by Salesforce. It's still using the `locale` parameter that has been deprecated in Summer 17.

> The locale parameter is deprecated for several methods in the AuraLocalizationService object. The validation for the locale parameter has also been tightened to allow locale values to match only the user’s Language or Locale settings in Salesforce. If the locale parameter is set to another value, it defaults to the user’s Language setting.

See here in the [Summer 17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_locale_api.htm)

The obvious fix for this is to not use the `ui:inputDate` component and I nearly have a replacement ready. When it is ready, I'll post it up to my github project. To see updates to this project, star or follow my library: [Datepicker](http://Datepicker)

Comment: I have updated the question with my issue and corresponding code. Please look into to it.

Comment: It's been fixed for a while. Grab all the code on the github project (including a couple of new components such as a datetime lib and a new inputDate component). Don't forget to update the Datepicker component too. It's all there and it all works. If you follow or star my project on github, it'll tell you when I make updates to the project.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!! Note, if you deploy to prod, you'll have to **ADD** the locale param back in a couple of places until Summer 17 goes live (in about 3 weeks)

Comment: Did salesforce make any chnage to "inputdate". I didn't deploy our new components for testing yet. It was broken in tetsing sandbox since it moved to summer '17. I didn't move my chnages yet, but the date picker started working in all spring and summer 17. Did salesforce revert back chnages to inputdate? Did you notice it?

Comment: don't deploy your changes to production (although you can actually change prod lightning components). The reason is: Salesforce made two changes in the recent update. 1. ui:inputDate now displays it's own horrible native picker when you click into it and you can't turn that off. 2. the locale thing is not live yet in prod, so your fixes for it won't work yet. Not long to wait though!

Comment: No i didn't deploy to prod yet. Its still on spring. thats fine. But one of my lower orgs is a preview instance. Its on summer 17 already. The date picker broke as soon as it turned to summer. But i observed that its working fine in that summer sandbox even though we didn't fix anything in that sandbox.